# How to make this 2 column table without using tables?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/pkLMC/

**the left column should shrink to fit**, and the right column should take up the remainder of the width of the page. It needs to work with IE7 as well

image of issue

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q8aW.png]

```
<style>
table
{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}
td
{
    vertical-align:top;
    border:1px solid green;
    background-color:orange;
}
.left
{
    /* trim the column to the minimum necessary width required to avoid overflow */
    width:1px;
}
.long
{
    /* this layout works whether the content of the right column wraps or not */
    /* display:none; */
}
</style>

<table>
<tr><td class="left">ABC</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor</td></tr>
<tr><td class="left">ABCDE</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td></tr>
<tr class="long"><td class="left">ABCDEFG</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</td></tr>
<tr class="long"><td class="left">ABCDEFGHI</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</td></tr>
<tr class="long"><td class="left">ABCDEFGHIJK</td><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry, i mean without using table/tr/td. Is it possible to do what this table layout does, but using divs and css instead

Comment: and with IE7 support >.<

Comment: you have perceived incorrectly Wesley. I've spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this out. Was just hoping SO might know something I don't before I give up and use tables

Comment: @giveupusetables - I'm assuming you want a "tabular" appearance in that the tops of the items should all align vertically with the other text they're associated with, and that the left edges of all the text blocks should align horizontally with each other. Is that correct?

Comment: @Rick yes that is correct. the biggest thing I can't figure out how to do without tables is getting the left column to shrink. I can set a fixed-width on a floated div, but it looks goofy when the content inside is much narrower than my fixed width

Comment: @Wesley I didn't include my evidence because they don't work :( and i thought it would distract from my fundamental question. I do want a fluid layout, but not a fixed-width left column. I want the left column to shrink to fit the largest content in that column.  edit: i guess you deleted your comment. will leave mine to further clarify what i'm looking for

Answer (score 7):

The data you present in your example is [tabular](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tabular) in nature in that it has both rows and columns.  Css without HTML tables is good for formatting stuff in columns (like a newspaper).  Once you have both rows and columns with variable width columns (like your data), tables (/table, /tr, /td, *etc.*) is the way to go.

You might want to stripe your rows.  Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/peavU/

Comment: my example is a simplified version of my irl content. i'm not opposed to using tables, but i think it's a stretch to say my content is actually tabular in nanture.

Answer (score 2):

Something to keep in mind is that using tables for layout is not a bad thing at all **IF** the information you're presenting is tabular in nature.

Using tables to arrange non-tabular data isn't good, but that doesn't mean that tables don't have their place.

On preview... what @DwB said.

Comment: my example looks like it might be tabular information, but it is just an example. my actual content is a little more complex, i'd feel better not using tables if i can find a good solution

Comment: @giveupusetables - That's understandable. Unfortunately, what you're dealing with is a variant of the [Project triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_triangle) in that there are three factors (in this case: vertical alignment, horizontal alignment, and column width) and while you can control any two, the third stays out of your control.  The compromise that will allow you to control all three is the table. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A definition list `<dl>` is perfect for the type of layout you have on your fiddle.

http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/

Comment: exactly. i'd like to use more semantically appropriate elements than table/tr/td, but if I can't find the css to get the visual layout to work, I'll stick with tables.

Comment: If your content is not tabular by nature, then it's a good idea to use table-less layout for presenting it. Check the definitions list I have posted in my answer. You can replace it with <div/>'s if your content is not a definition nature either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using div tags instead? They are more organized, efficient, and can adjust to multiple screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

I agree with both @DwB and @Diodeus. Means, if you have really tabular data, the best you can do is to use tables. But, if your list is actually a list of definitions, then it makes sense to convert to `<dl>` [like in the example](http://www.webdevout.net/test?0L):

**HTML**

```
<dl>
    <dt>THIS IS THE TITLE</dt>
    <dd>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</dd> 

    <dt>THIS IS ANOTHER TITLE</dt>
    <dd>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS**

```
dl {
    width: 100%;
    background: Orange;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
dt {
    width: 10em;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
dd {
    margin-left: 12em;
    padding: 1em;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;    
}
```

Comment: this would be fine, except for the fixed width on dt. I want all the dt elements to stretch to fit the widest content of all the dt elements

Comment: Then you will have to either use JS solution in addition to the one above (to get the width of the longest DT and set this width to all DT's), or fallback to the table-based solution, @giveupusetables

Answer (score 0):

I can get a bit crazy using lists, but here is my two cents...with a jsFiddle example: [Table like layout using lists](http://jsfiddle.net/slim81/AVASe/1/)

The code should resize and the text won't wrap, utilizing the "text-overflow: ellipsis;" css rule.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<!-- "table" header" -->
<li class="col1 th">Column 1 header</li>
<li class="col2 th">Column 2 header</li>
<!-- "table" rows -->
<li class="col1">data</li>
<li class="col2">data</li>
<li class="col1">data</li>
<li class="col2">data</li>
<li class="col1">data</li>
<li class="col2">data</li>
<li class="col1">data</li>
<li class="col2">data</li>
<li class="col1">data</li>
<li class="col2">data</li>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    list-style-type: none;
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
ul:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.col1, .col2{
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    padding: .25em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;                   
    overflow: hidden; 
    text-overflow:    ellipsis;
}
.col1 {
    clear: left;
    width: 30%;
}
.col2{
    width: 70%;
}
.th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Hopefully that helps!